# Are there sandboxing concepts for proprietary binary kernel modules in linux?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, sandbox

Quite a lot has been going on to advance inter-process security (`UID` the same) and priveledge dropping in `userland`, yet it is common that proprietary linux kernel components are used (it seems that GPLv2 does not really solve closed source kernel module issue sadly).

My quesiton is about concept (existing or in developmen) to "sandbox" a otherwise closed source kernel module.

It seems to me that in times of justified paranoia (wikileaks,post snowden) people have been looking for ways how to prevent a potential backdoor in a proprietary kernel module, right?

Comment: In Linux, kernel code does not have memory protection with respect to other kernel code. Any kind of sandboxing concept is therefore a non-starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a sandboxing concept for proprietary drivers. It's called userland drivers.

If you run code inside the kernel, it has access to everything, so it's impossible to sandbox it. (Impossible with respect to the Linux system — that system could run in a virtual machine, and then the VM would be doing the sandboxing.)

Userland drivers are possible for some kinds of peripherals. For example, some USB peripherals can be driven from userland via [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) and [usbfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/usb/usbfs.html). Filesystems can be implemented in userland via [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).

Given that a malicious driver for a peripheral can usually leverage its access to the peripheral to access the rest of the system (e.g. by configuring the peripheral for [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) and thus accessing arbitrary memory), there isn't much point in attempting to sandbox a driver. If you don't trust the driver, don't use it.

It's possible to do some sandboxing by running the driver inside a virtual machine, and configuring the hypervisor to allow the VM to access only a specific peripheral. This is only useful if the peripheral itself only has access to a specific part of memory, which can be done with an [IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit) (the IOMMU has to remain under control of the hypervisor, of course). Not all systems support such sandboxing — once again, if you don't trust the peripheral, why would you have it in your computer?

Comment: Those drivers in userspace seem somewhat microkernel-ly and it is good to know about that, indeed I should have been aware of FUSE already, as I indeed even used it. As regards the trailing question about "why would you have it in your computer?" I am myself torn between correct Stallmann attitude to rather use nothing than unfree soft/hardware and the mere fact that rarely have I the chance to find devices (i.e. category smartphone) that offers "only free drivers". The question of sandboxing occurs naturally at least since post Snowden

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible and CPUs give some support to restrict accesses of part of kernel codes.

But there are two difficulties: proprietary kernel modules are programmed by hardware companies, so, even if kernel could restrict access to certain addresses, the hardware side could have unrestricted access.

The second difficulty: I doubt kernel people will implement such plan: an implicit linux kernel rule states "don't favorite closed source people", and such plan will make they tasks easier/more acceptable.

Comment: the aspect of not favouring closed source code is something I have not considered enough and is interisting input.